# Hygieia Specific,UI, Gulp - How To

Tags: gulp, hygieia

Query related to opensource tool Hygieia. On the Gulp scripts https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia/blob/v2.0.0/UI/gulpfile.js
`Gulp serve` serves the application. here are few queries i need help with

1. In version 1.5.0 gulp task runner had gulp serve:dist, which served only minified content, 2.0 does not seem to do that
2. gulp serve starts the app @ port 3000, how do i control it for each instance, as i intend to run couple of instances(diff versions) on the same vm.

   3. When UI is served @ localhost:3000/ , all the content is served from
      localhost:3000/# and localhost:3000/bower_components .. etc..
      i want to move the content to be served under localhost:3000/WebApp/
      So that all the URLs are under a specific Virt Directory.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

TIA,
Tx

Answer (score 0):

your question not much clear. still if i understand your question correctly-
your current hygieia configuration working correctly. you just want to run multiple instances of same application.

for that you have to make changes in UI>gulpfile.js